# Problems with Zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server

I have downloaded and installed Zend Server community edition. I am on a mac.
I have tried to changed the path in

```
  /usr/local/zend/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

so that it pointed at a test file in my documents folder. However, when I type

```
  http://localhost:10081/test.php
```

into my browser, I just get 404- page not found.

Any suggestions? I am new to web stuff and don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I guess apache does not have permissions to access "My Documents" of your windows user

Comment: If i correct, not to keep your docroot in "My Documents"

Comment: Where would you suggest putting it?

Comment: In default area where it was...

Comment: Typically, there's an 'htdocs' folder which is where the server reads your files. The Zend Community Docs (http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/zend-server-community-edition.htm#mac_osx_installation.htm) suggest that the server is looking for files in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was trying to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find step by step directions for setting up your local environment on a mac:

http://www.cmiwebstudio.com/blog/zend-server-ce-for-mac-osx-10-lion/

and some other posts that may also help here:

http://www.cmiwebstudio.com/blog/tag/zend-server-ce/